# How to move signature node in signed XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, sign

I have this example of XML. What I need is to sign the xml with Java. The problem is that I get the 'Signature' node in wrong place..

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fu="http://www.fu.gov.si/" xmlns:xd="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<soapenv:Body>
    <fu:BusinessPremiseRequest Id="data">
        <fu:Header>
            <fu:MessageID>20DF8D44-ABBE-76BA-E053-AA02010AEA8E</fu:MessageID>
            <fu:DateTime>2015-09-24T12:07:28</fu:DateTime>
        </fu:Header>
        <fu:BusinessPremise>
            <fu:TaxNumber>99999862</fu:TaxNumber>
            <fu:BusinessPremiseID>P001</fu:BusinessPremiseID>
            <fu:BPIdentifier>
                <fu:RealEstateBP>
                    <fu:PropertyID>
                        <fu:CadastralNumber>2606</fu:CadastralNumber>
                        <fu:BuildingNumber>6967</fu:BuildingNumber>
                        <fu:BuildingSectionNumber>1</fu:BuildingSectionNumber>
                    </fu:PropertyID>
                    <fu:Address>
                        <fu:Street>TEST</fu:Street>
                        <fu:HouseNumber>7</fu:HouseNumber>
                        <fu:HouseNumberAdditional>C</fu:HouseNumberAdditional>
                        <fu:Community>KOPER</fu:Community>
                        <fu:City>KOPER</fu:City>
                        <fu:PostalCode>6000</fu:PostalCode>
                    </fu:Address>
                </fu:RealEstateBP>
            </fu:BPIdentifier>
            <fu:ValidityDate>2010-09-24</fu:ValidityDate>
            <fu:SoftwareSupplier>
                <fu:TaxNumber>10031685</fu:TaxNumber>
            </fu:SoftwareSupplier>
            <fu:SpecialNotes>Primer prijave poslovnega prostora</fu:SpecialNotes>
        </fu:BusinessPremise>
    </fu:BusinessPremiseRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Now I want to sign the xml with my private key in Java.

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        List transforms = null;

        XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");

        Reference ref = fac.newReference(
                "#data",
                fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA256, null),
                transforms,
                null,
                null
        );

        SignedInfo si = fac.newSignedInfo(fac.newCanonicalizationMethod(CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE,
                (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null),
                fac.newSignatureMethod("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256", null),
                Collections.singletonList(ref));

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);

        Document doc = (Document) dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));


        KeyStore p12 = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
        p12.load(new FileInputStream("c:/cert/furspeter.pfx"), "PWD".toCharArray());


        Enumeration e = p12.aliases();
        String alias = (String) e.nextElement();
        System.out.println("Alias certifikata:" + alias);
        Key privateKey = p12.getKey(alias, "PWD".toCharArray());

        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry
                = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) p12.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("PWD".toCharArray()));

        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) keyEntry.getCertificate();

        KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();

        System.out.println(cert.getSerialNumber());

        X509IssuerSerial x509IssuerSerial = kif.newX509IssuerSerial(cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName(), cert.getSerialNumber());

        List x509Content = new ArrayList();
        System.out.println("ime: " + cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
        x509Content.add(cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
        x509Content.add(x509IssuerSerial);

        X509Data xd = kif.newX509Data(x509Content);
        KeyInfo ki = kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(xd));
        DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(privateKey, doc.getDocumentElement());
        XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, ki);
        signature.sign(dsc);

        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("c:/SignedXml.xml");
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
        trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(os));
```

what I want is to get 'Signature' node inside 'fu:BusinessPremiseRequst' node.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:fu="http://www.fu.gov.si/" xmlns:xd="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<soapenv:Body>
<fu:BusinessPremiseRequest Id="data">
<fu:Header>...</fu:Header>
<fu:BusinessPremise>...</fu:BusinessPremise>
     <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">...</Signature>
</fu:BusinessPremiseRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
```

In my case I get  node in wrong position (example below)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fu="http://www.fu.gov.si/" xmlns:xd="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<soapenv:Body>
<fu:BusinessPremiseRequest Id="data">
 ....
</fu:BusinessPremiseRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">..</Signature>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What I am doing wrong in my Java example? or how to move  node inside  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake probably is here: `DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(privateKey, doc.getDocumentElement());`
You are telling to `DOMSignContext` that `Signature` should be attached to main document element.

If you want this in `fu:BusinessPremiseRequest`, you should firstly get that node, and pass it as parameter in `new DOMSignContext()` constructor.

Comment: Can someone help me in this? It's first time that I use Java to sign xml.. Can I use some Xpath expression to get a node?

Comment: I have done this: with xpath I have extracted NodeList.  nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                System.out.println("node length: " + nodes.getLength());
                if (nodes.getLength() == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Can't find node with id: " + ID);
                    return;
                }

                nodeToSign = nodes.item(0);
                sigParent = nodeToSign.getParentNode();

Comment: And now do you have your signature at the place you expected? :)

Comment: The problem is that <Signature> is not inside fu:BusiessPremiseRequest but below this tag...

Comment: So my answer isn't correct? Did you pass "fu:BusinessPremiseRequest" node to `new DOMSignContext()` constructor?

Comment: nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET); nodeToSign = nodes.item(0);
sigParent = nodeToSign.getParentNode();DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(
                privateKey,
                sigParent
        );  what I get is that <Signature> is below fu:BusinessPremiseRequest...

Comment: try this:
`Node node = document.getElementsByTagName("fu:BusinessPremiseRequest").item(0);
DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(privateKey, node);
` instead of `DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(privateKey, doc.getDocumentElement());` in code from your question.

Comment: Read this - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/crypto/dsig/dom/DOMSignContext.html#DOMSignContext(java.security.Key,%20org.w3c.dom.Node). Parameter, that you're passing to costructor, is a parrent node for signature. It means, that signature will be append inside this node. So if in your case signature is bellow something, you should pass exactly that node, inside which signature should be

Comment: Oh ;) thats ok! thank you! now I get <Signature> inside fu:BusinessPremiseRequest  Thank you!